# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend

I want to get posts from Vk and add them to postgressQl. But hapenning nothink.

What I do wrong, and how can I add Posts to My datsBse.
I could get Posts and I see them.

Entity:

```js
@Entity('tutors')
export class TutorEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column()
    posts: string;
    
    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;
    
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updateAt: Date;
}
```

dto for creat posts:

```js
export class CreateTutorDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    posts: string;
}
```

My Controllers:

```js
@Controller('tutors')
export class TutorsController {
    constructor(private readonly tutorsService: TutorsService) {}
    
    @Get()
    create() {
     return this.tutorsService.findPostFirstGroup();
    }
}
```

Service:
Data closest Object.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TutorsService {
    constructor(
      @InjectRepository(TutorEntity)
      private repository: Repository<TutorEntity>,
    ) {}
    
    create(dto: {
      posts: string;
    }) {
      return this.repository.save(dto);
    }
    
    console.log(this.repository)
    await this.repository.create(
      {
        posts: 'post',
      }
    )
}
```

Module:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
     TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TutorEntity]),
     ConfigModule.forRoot(),
     HttpModule,
    ],
    controllers: [TutorsController],
    providers: [TutorsService],
    exports: [TutorsService],
})
export class TutorsModule {}
```

In console I see:

```java
repositories: Map(2) {
    [class UserEntity] => [Repository],
    [class TutorEntity] => [Circular *1]
},
```

Comment: based on the code you're showing: `this.repository` doesn't exist. That's what the error means: you are calling `.create` on something that doesn't exist. And on that note: [**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** — copy or type the text into the question](/help/how-to-ask). (emphasis not mine, this happens _so much_ we need to bold and all-caps it. And people still do it =)

Comment: okay, I posted code with error.  So, I need to understand why I don't have this repository

Comment: unfortunately, this is going to first be on you to track down: `this.repository` is undefined, which if I'm looking at your `TutorsService` class, you've defined as a private property, but I don't see any code that actually "fills it in": why does the constructor not have a repository argument so that you're guaranteed its never undefined?

Comment: I rewrite code now, like this:                                                                                     constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TutorEntity)
        private repository: Repository<TutorEntity>,
    ) {}

Comment: I don'have error, but I can't add somethink to repositiry)

Comment: I see two repositories  repositories: Map(2) {
      [class UserEntity] => [Repository],
      [class TutorEntity] => [Circular *1]
    },

Answer (score 0):

I decided my ptoblem.
I needed to write

```
async findPostFirstGroup() {
  await this.create({ posts: 'sdsdds' });
}
```